# How to define entity for the following table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have two tables T_users and M_Album as below:

T_Users

[image]

T_Album

[image]

2 foreign key fields UserID, ParentID in M_Album  and both having primary key field ID in T_Users.How to write the entity code in code first approach?

I created

```
 M_Album = new HashSet<M_Album>();
```

and

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<M_Album> M_Album { get; set; }
```

in T_Users.And

`public virtual T_Users T_Users { get; set; }`  in M_Album

Also created:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T_Users>()
              .HasMany(e => e.M_Album)
              .WithOptional(e => e.T_Users)
              .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<T_Users>()
         .HasMany(e => e.M_Album)
         .WithOptional(e => e.T_Users)
         .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);
```

Is this work fine or any other method?

Comment: UserID and ParentID of M_Album, both need to point to ID of T_Users?

Comment: @sachin How to point to ID of T_Users?please share code if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you have two FKs to another table, you should also specify two `IColletion`s at principal table declaration. Try use data annotations approach instead of fluen api:

```
public class T_User
{
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<T_Album> userAlbums {get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual ICollection<T_Album> parentAlbums {get; set;}

    //other stuff...
}

public class T_Album
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public virtual T_User User {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public virtual T_User Parent {get; set;}

    //other stuff...
}
```